# Expect Script Special Character Password?

Tags: php

I am trying to get expect work with special characters but I couldnt make it.

Calling the expect script in a php with shell_exec and special characters are causing expect to fail or unable to login.

```
shell_exec("expect test.exp $sshport $srvip $pass > /lists.txt;");
```

Update(solution):
Fixed by simply $pass=escapeshellarg($pass);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you neeed to use `escapeshellcmd`

**escapeshellcmd — Escape shell metacharacters**

```
$command ="expect test.exp $sshport $srvip $pass > /lists.txt;"
 shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($command));
```

this may or may not work better:

```
$pass=escapeshellarg($pass);
shell_exec("expect test.exp $sshport $srvip $pass > /lists.txt;");
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in test.php on line 2. 

Even if I remove / then it returns 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in test.php on line 4

Comment: whats line 2? whats line 13?

Comment: arg, left a type sorry

Comment: there was a space nothing. I have cleared the space and now error on line 4. Here is the code, it is only your code in the file.

<?
$command ="expect test.exp $sshport $srvip $pass." > lists.txt;"
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($command));
?>

Comment: solution 1 was still returning error. However, the second solution $pass=escapeshellarg($pass); works like a dream and tested all special characters, thanks mate.